# Custom string compare function explanation

Tags: c, function, for-loop, while-loop, user-defined-functions

In this code how does the function `same_string` work? Please can anyone explain this code?

Is there any way to write it with a **for loop**?

Or any easier way?

The code:

```
struct student {
    char name[20];
};

int same_string(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    while (*s1 == *s2) {
        if (*s1 == '\0')
            return 1;
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    struct student s[10];
    int n, i, j, count;
    for (n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
    printf("Enter student name: ");
        if (scanf("%19s%*[^\n]", s[n].name) < 1)
        break;
    }
    count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (i != j && same_string(s[i].name, s[j].name)) {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n%d students have same name\n\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%19s%*[^\n]"` will not return until there is input after input like `"Drhunter\n"`.  Consider `fgets()` (and then lop off the trialing `\n\`) to handle names with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The function is pretty straight forward. Remember that in C, a string is terminated with `\0`

```
int same_string(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    while (*s1 == *s2) {  // Check if current character is equal for both strings
        if (*s1 == '\0')  // If one string has ended, both have and they are equal
            return 1;
        s1++;   // Next character for string 1
        s2++;   // Next character for string 2
    }
    return 0;  // If the while condition fails, they are not equal
}
```

> Is three any way to write the function code for same_string with for loop?

Yes. You can always rewrite a for loop to a while loop and vice versa. In this case, the absolute simplest way is to just change

```
while (*s1 == *s2)
```

to

```
for( ; *s1 == *s2; )
```

and keep the rest of the body. Something that would look a bit better would be

```
for( ; *s1 == *s2; s1++, s2++) {
    if (*s1 == '\0')
        return 1;
}
```

or

```
for(size_t i = 0; s1[i] == s2[i]; i++) {
    if(s1[i] == '\0')
        return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> In this code how does the function `same_string` work? Please can anyone explain this code?

It basically iterates through the characters of both strings, if the characters are equal the cycle continues, if the first argument string reaches it's end `\0` that means that the second also reached its end, the strings are equal so the return is `1`, otherwise, if the characters differ in a given iteration, the strings are not equal, the cycle breaks and the return is `0`.

`same_string` is a simplified version of [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) without the negative return option, and inverted return for equality, `strcmp` retuns 0 if the strings are equal whereas the custom function returns 1.

In your case you do not need to know the lexicographical order so the custom implementation should work fine.

> Is there any way to write it with a **for loop**?

The code seems good to me. You can have a `for` loop with minor adjustments:

```
int same_string(const char *s1, const char *s2){
    for( ; *s1 == *s2; s1++, s2++) {
        if (*s1 == '\0')
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> Or any easier way?

If you want you can use the mentioned `strcmp` library function instead of the custom `same_string` but you would need to `#include <string.h>`:

```
//...
if (i != j && !strcmp(s[i].name, s[j].name)){
    count++;
    break;
}
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through all the characters while all characters are all the same.

If there's a pair of characters that are not the same, the loop ends, then return 0.

else, there must be an `'\0'` to terminate the string(`const char*`), which means all the characters before it are all the same, thus return 1

and it's easy to implement this, like:

```c
int same_string(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
  for (int i = 0; s1[i] == s2[i]; i++) {
    if (s1[i] == '\0') {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```